# seleccionar coincidencia evento Keyup de JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estoy haciendo un buscador con `ajax` en el evento `jquery Keyup` para que me muestre coincidencias según la letra con la que el usuario empieza a teclear y se pueda seleccionar una opción de las opciones que devuelve el `ajax`, pero no se como hacer para que se pueda seleccionar la opción y agregarla al `textbox` donde esta tecleando el usuario, para después poder buscar esa opción con un botón en una BD

mi código es:

```js
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#filtroBusqueda").change(function () {            
            var op = $(this).val();

            switch (op) {

                case "rs":
                    $("#rs").css({ 'display': 'block' });
                    $("#ln").css({ 'display': 'none' });
                    $("#nc").css({ 'display': 'none' });
                    break;
                case "ln":
                    $("#ln").css({ 'display': 'block' });
                    $("#rs").css({ 'display': 'none' });
                    $("#nc").css({ 'display': 'none' });
                    break;
                case "nc":
                    $("#nc").css({ 'display': 'block' });               
                    $("#rs").css({ 'display': 'none' });
                    $("#ln").css({ 'display': 'none' });
            }
        });

        $("#txtRazon").keyup(function () {
            var valor = $(this).val();
            //alert(valor);
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: "coincidencia",
                //contentType: false,
                data: { "valorBusqueda": valor },
                //processData: false,
                //cache: false,
                success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                    $("#resultadosBusqueda").hide().html(data).fadeIn("fast");                    
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <h5><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></span>Búsqueda</h5>
  <form id="registrationForm" method="post" class="form-horizontal mitad" action="#">

    <div class="form-group">

      <div class="col-lg-12">
        <select name="filtroBusqueda" id="filtroBusqueda" class="form-control">
          <option value="" disabled selected>Selecciona Opción</option>
          <option value="rs">Nombre</option>
          <option value="ln">Línea</option>
          <option value="nc">Número cuenta</option>
        </select>

      </div>

    </div>

    <div id="rs" style="display:none">
      <div class="form-group">

        <label class="col-md-2 control-label">Nombre</label>

        <div class="col-md-10">
          <input type="text" id="txtRazon" class="form-control" />

        </div>

      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="ln" style="display:none">
      <div class="form-group">

        <label class="col-lg-3 control-label">Número telefonico</label>

        <div class="col-lg-12">
          <input type="text" id="txtTelefono" class="form-control" />

        </div>

      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="nc" style="display:none">
      <div class="form-group">

        <label class="col-lg-3 control-label">Número cuenta</label>

        <div class="col-lg-12">
          <input type="text" id="txtCuenta" class="form-control" />

        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="resultadosBusqueda"></div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

perdon por no contestar tu pregunta. Yo he utilizado(como te recomiendan en la otra respuesta) el plugin de jquery-ui en mi caso lo que hice fue cargar un arreglo con los nombres de productos($results2) y con jquery solo hice:

```
function monkeyPatchAutocomplete() {
        $.ui.autocomplete.prototype._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
            item.label = item.label.replace(new RegExp("(?![^&;]+;)(?!<[^<>]*)(" + $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(this.term) + ")(?![^<>]*>)(?![^&;]+;)", "gi"), "<span style='font-weight:bold;color:Blue;'>$1</span>");
            return $("<li></li>")
                    .data("item.autocomplete", item)
                    .append("<a style='text-decoration: none;border: none;'>" + item.label + "</a>")
                    .appendTo(ul);
        };
    }



   <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    monkeyPatchAutocomplete();
    var languages = <?php echo json_encode($results2)?>;
        $("#search").autocomplete({
            source: languages
        });
```

y mi input con el id search. Espero te sirva de algo

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2435964/jqueryui-how-can-i-custom-format-the-autocomplete-plug-in-results